# iPhone - Change app icon pointed to by info.plist within the application?

Tags: iphone, plist, bundle

Is there any way to change the 47x47 PNG, pointed to within info.plist, for the iPhone springboard icon from within code?

I understand I can add a translation and change the springboard icon per language that the iPhone supports via a changed info.plist per language, but I would like to change the springboard icon for my iPhone app based on a user preference within the app.

Any ideas?

I haven't tried this, but can a file be copied over another within an app bundle? Could I ship with info.plist pointing to "base.png" then replace "base.png" with another PNG I package with my app from within code?

Thanks.

--Batgar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This cannot be done - an iPhone application main bundle is read only, so you cannot change your app icon from within your app.

Comment: Thanks zPesk. I figured as much. So it appears my only recourse is to ship out an entirely different app with the different icon, or to come up with a general icon that spans the "marketing space" of the application and customize internally.

Thanks again.

Comment: alternatively, when you submit an update to your app, you could alter the app's icon

Comment: To make a long story short, I work for a company that has many sister companies. They want the app branded for each sister company at the springboard without having to submit a different app per sister company. We have 10 different sister companies, and the only major difference is going to be the springboard icon. That said, I am pretty sure we will find a need to customize a given string or image for a specific company, which means that we will need to ship the app per company anyway. Such is life.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a new target (with the relevant icon) for each "sister" app and that will allow you to compile multiple apps using the same code base. Hope this helps!