# How to change app icon within In-App Purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

Is it possible even to change from demo icon to full version image after purchasing full version via InApp Purchase? Or should I make two versions with lite/full icons ?

Comment: Please See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1223787/878414

Comment: I have read it, but it was in 2009, so i was hoping for some changes ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45602449/195186

This was true before iOS 10.3 only:

> No. This is not possible. The icon is fixed.

Comment: This answer seems to be obsolete. See my answer for new information.

Answer (score 3):

UIApplication has a new instance method that will do what you want. The Apple docs spell out exactly what you need to do to accomplish this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, since iOS apps run in a sandbox and can therefore not write (while they can read) the app's bundle, where the icon is located.

Answer (score 0):

1) In info.plist set up key *Icon file* with value **../Documents/icon.png**. 
2) Add key *Icon already includes gloss effects* with value **YES**
3) In first launch move picture to **/Documents/icon.png**

After second launch Icon app will be changed!

If you change icon.png in Documents folder need to make respiring for refresh Icon app.