# How to change the app icon or install new app on device on behave of in-App purchase upgrade?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icons, in-app-purchase

I'm looking for a way to let the user have the ability to upgrade their App from a free App to a pro/plus/HD App. I have some experience with in-App purchases but for this client I need to adjust the appicon (because the user can upgrade their App).

On stackoverflow it turned out that changing the Appicon is impossible because it's within the App it's sandbox environment ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515135/how-to-change-app-icon-within-in-app-purchase)).

I saw some cool app which had the option to let a new App be installed on the user it's iPhone with a new App icon. This all by means of an in-App purchase.

Can anyone explain me or refer to some steps which are necessary to accomplish my needs?

EDIT:

Is it perhaps possible to create an App just as you add a link from safari to your homescreen and afterwords let this function as a hyperlink for my app? (using shared secret)

Comment: Are you sure they weren't just use the `SKStoreProductViewController` to display a pro-version of their app? Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12682657/1176156

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot change the app icon, as you know. Also, you cannot install an app on the user's device that does not come from the App Store. The best you could do is utilize an in app purchase, and when the purchase completes, point them to the link of the app on the store. Your app will not be accepted however, and the pro app will be on the App Store for free. The best you can do is either take "free" out of the icon altogether or have two different apps.

Comment: This answer seems to be obsolete. See my answer for new information.

Comment: This is now possible to do. See my answer to the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515135/how-to-change-app-icon-within-in-app-purchase?rq=1