# How to change application icon during installation (after deployment)?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone - Change app icon pointed to by info.plist within the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223787/iphone-change-app-icon-pointed-to-by-info-plist-within-the-application)

The application icon should be changed /or/ changing Icon during installation. I have no idea about doing this. Please if anybody know the solution?

Comment: change icon on the home screen? not possible without using private API

Comment: [this cannot be done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223787/iphone-change-app-icon-pointed-to-by-info-plist-within-the-application)

Comment: Not possible, apple will reject straight away. Use of private APIs is not allowed and you would need one to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Apple do not allow this.

Your app goes to itunes then only you install it. Once it is downloaded and installed from there you can't change it.